# How do I make my footer go down as I add content?

Tags: html, css, footer

I structured my site like this:

```
<body>

   <div class="main">

      <div class="header">
          content
      </div> 

      <div class="section">
         content
      </div>

      <div class="sidebar">
         content
      </div>

      <div class="clearing"></div>

      <div class="footer">
         content
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

and the css

```
.main {
        position:relative;
        width:908px;
        margin-top:0px;
        border:solid 0px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

.header {

        position:relative;
        height:200px;
        margin: auto;
    }


  div.section {
            float:left;
        position:absolute;
        width: 584px;
        height:500px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align:left;
        }

  div.sidebar{
        float:right;
        position:relative;
        width: 324px;
        height:500px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align:left; 
    }

   .clearing {

        clear:both;
    }



   .footer {
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:908px;
    height:300px;
   }
```

When I add content to the div section, I goes all over the footer. The footer is fixed at that point, and as content is added, the page grows and the footer remains still.

What I have to do everytime I add content is to increase in the css file either the height of the section or the height of the sidebar - either one would work - but I increase both heights (section and sidebar) to the same value, because it seems the right thing to do. The footer then is pushed down as the height of the section and the sidebar grows.

However, if I atribute a height to the content that I add to the section, it does not have any effect on the position of the footer, perhaps because it has nothing to do with the height of the section itself.

Is there a way to make the footer respond to the space the content being added will occupy, and just automatically move along, remaining at the bottom of the page ?

Comment: I have had this problem. I followed Css-tricks suggested sticky footer tutorial and it helped me fix this issue, I highly recommend you try it. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: Remove the absolute positioning on .section

Comment: At the very least, you need to put your divs above the footer into another div with the clearing element at the end to contain them all.

Comment: I tried the sticky footer, didn't work for me... I changed to relative, and nothing happened. I changed th position of the divs, with th clearing element at the end, it didn't work... but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have `position:absolute` set on your `.section` div, which will only ever use its CSS height value for the amount of space it takes up, regardless of its actual content. Removing that absolute position should solve your problems. There's (almost) always a way around absolute positioning. In your example, it seems completely unnecessary.

Here's a helpful site for CSS positioning:
http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Hope it helps!

Comment: If you're worried about the height of this div for your layout, I'd suggest using the "min-height:" value as a means of appropriately letting it expand and influence the flow of your page in addition to getting rid of the absolute positioning.

Comment: i changed to relative... it didn't work. The layout stays the same, but the footer still behaves as before.

Comment: @user2363043: You'll also want to remove the `height` attribute in the CSS for the `.section`. I copied your HTML and CSS verbatim into my localhost on my computer, added 5 paragraphs of lorem ipsum to the `.section` div, and removed the `height` and `position`, and all behaved as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.footer {
position:relative;
left:0;
bottom:0;
width:908px;
height:300px;
```

}

Also when putting 0, there is no need to add the px.

Answer (score 0):

I am checking the `CSS` code and have spotted `position` in every `div`. Try to balance it because it affects other `divs` 
Also try

```
.footer{
   clear: both
}
```